# Whether the terms Bases function and Basis function are same or differen?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I have came accross few lines in my reading/discussion like

1. any signal can be represented by summation of elementary Signals.these elementary signals are called as basis(sometimes read as bases?) functions.

2.Also,in Fourier series ,the terms like bases functions are there to do Fourier decomposition.

3.Any image can be represented using summation of basis (in some discussions read as bases) images .

I am a bit confused with the two terms in functions i.e. bases function and basis function. I thought they are one and the same.

So whether terms **Bases functions** and **Basis functions** are same or different?

Comment: Give us some context. Maybe one sentence from the literature using each?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Sir,I have edited my question. Please,go through it.

Comment: "Bases" is the plural form of the word "basis". The phrase "bases functions" sounds very strange to my ears and I don't think I know any scenario where it would be natural to use it. "Basis functions", on the other hand, is used all the time (and it means the functions which are members of a given basis for some function space).

Comment: A paraphrase isn't good enough to tell what's going on. We'd need to see the exact quote to tell you how the words are being used. If your three examples are exact word-for-word quotes, it just shows that what you are reading is being written by people who are not native English speakers, and so no conclusion can be drawn about what they mean.

Comment: @Gerry Myeson pls read there are both words in discussion dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22956/fourier-decomposition

Comment: @Hans Lundmark  pls read there are both words in discussion
 dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22956/fourier-decomposition

Comment: I only see one person in that discussion using "bases function", and it is clear to me that that person is making many mistakes in English usage, so draw a conclusion from that.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson but in the answer both words are present.so which is right word "bases" or "basis"

Comment: No. Only one person is using "bases" on that page.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson sir in the 1st answer both words are there

Comment: Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". Only one person uses the word, "bases". And that person doesn't know English.

Comment: Any further questions?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yes sir :-) can u give simple explaination on.....

for any given signal,how do we find the basis functions mathematically ?

Comment: Don't know. Why not post that as a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been said that the universal language of Science is broken English.

OP has only provided one example of a person writing "bases functions", and that person's English is, shall we say, a non-standard dialect. Until/unless further examples are provided, it seems safe to say that "bases functions" is an idiosyncratic way of saying "basis functions".